# ASP.NET string value as command for query

Tags: sql, asp.net, command

I have an asp.net application I have a multiple sql query for different values. How can I add string value to sql command. This is the resource page

[image]

```
 SqlCommand kapi1cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*)from(select a.GIRIS_ZAMANI, a.CIKIS_ZAMANI, a.PLAKA, a.UCRET, b.KAMERA_ADI, ACIKLAMA from ARAC_CIKIS a left join KAMERALAR b on b.KAMERA_ID = a.CIKIS_KAMERA_ID where a.CIKIS_ZAMANI between cast(cast(sysutcdatetime() as date) as datetime) + cast('00:00:00' as datetime) and cast(cast(sysutcdatetime() as date) as datetime)+ cast('23:59:59' as datetime)and  ACIKLAMA='@Kuzey.Resources.GeneralTitles.kapi1') A", cn1);
```

`@Kuzey.Resources.GeneralTitles.kapi1`

> ACIKLAMA= @Kuzey.Resources.GeneralTitles.kapi1

Comment: Check for [SqlParameter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I didnt get it completely can you show example

Comment: Check for examples in [SqlParameter Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameter__ctor_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_System_Int32_)